# Missing question and user?

Tags: discussion, searching

Well, this is embarrassing.

I've spent the last 20 minutes looking for a particular question on main but haven't been able to find it at all. This question involves something like the growth of $n!/(a!b!)$ whenever $a+b$ divides $n$, or something like that.

> Does anyone have a link to the question that I'm looking for?

I clearly remember that one of the users involved in either asking or answering this question was called "chatish", and this person had been on the high-rep pages for the last quarter (something like 3k rep over 3 months or something, astronomically high). Now there is no sign of this user. So,

> What happened to chatish?

Thanks, and sorry for the lousy memory!

Comment: The question is here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/137920/how-ab-can-grow-when-ab-mid-n/142996#142996

Comment: @Lucia Thanks for the link to the question!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Lucia linked in the comments above, the question you're looking for is available at [How $a+b$ can grow when $a!b! \mid n!$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/137920/how-ab-can-grow-when-ab-mid-n/142996#142996).

That user, and some related ones, were deleting for abusing the voting system.

Comment: If, perchance, any reader of this comment realizes they've been abusing the voting system, I'd advise they contact us by email privately, and we'll clean up nice and discreetly. We don't like it, however, when we discover such examples ourselves.

Comment: This explains the funky voting in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/142505/rings-in-which-every-element-is-a-sum-of-two-commuting-idempotents/142516?__=712753518.

Comment: This is a general question motivated by this incident along the lines of @BenjaminSteinberg's remark. To what extent do you want to be informed if one *suspects* something like this could be happening? (I ask specifically since I did get at one point somewhat suspecting there was something strange going, but somehow felt uncomfortable raising the issue. I have an answer on a q where that user also has/had one and the voting felt a bit strange, in the sense of more than usual late votes, thus I noticed, but then there could have been other reasons too explaining the votes).

Comment: Hmm, I don't know, feels a bit like snitching on classmates! Maybe better to just leave it to us. We've got pretty good tools, especially since 2.0.

Comment: Yes, it somehow felt quite denunciatory, which is why I was uncomfortable.

Comment: I feel like I should know this but:  What happens when I user is deleted for abusing the voting system?  Do all of that user's questions and answers simply disappear (or at least become visible only to high-rep users)?  If the questions and answers are valuable, ought they remain posted?  Should this be a feature request?

Comment: @StevenLandsburg, the mods can leave the questions and answers if they want to like in the question I linked.

Comment: When a user is deleted the content is untouched. The user name in the attribution box simply no longer links to anything.

Comment: @Scott: By the way -- under which circumstances are the deleted user's cast votes preserved / revoked?

Comment: @StefanKohl: When a user is deleted, all of the votes they cast are deleted too. Their posts with nonnegative score are preserved but the rest are deleted. In particular, users who downvoted these posts recover their 1 point payment.

Comment: See also [this answer on meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it/126471#126471).